# Divide the interval of months with respect to value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

The problem: I have a data frame recording status of customers over periods of time. For each customer (group) I would like to divide the time interval into "Start" and "Finish" with respect to the status they have in that period.

For example, I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group1',
                    'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group3'],
               'Month': ['2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12',
                    '2019-04', '2019-05', '2019-06', '2019-07', '2019-08', '2019-09', '2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12'],
               'Status': ['Passive', 'Passive', 'Passive', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Passive', 'Passive',
                    'Active', 'Active', 'Passive', 'Passive', 'Passive', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active', 'Active']})
```

I would like to transfer it into this structure:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['group1', 'group1', 'group1', 'group2', 'group2', 'group2', 'group3'],
                   'From': ['2019-05', '2019-08', '2019-11', '2019-04', '2019-06', '2019-09', '2019-12'],
                   'To': ['2019-07', '2019-10', '2019-12', '2019-05', '2019-08', '2019-11', '2019-12'],
                   'Status': ['Passive', 'Active', 'Passive', 'Active', 'Passive', 'Active', 'Active']})
```

Without the "Status"-variable, it would be quite simple with groupby and aggfunc to find "min" and "max" period in each group. However, I don't know how to take the "Status"-variable into account. The problem is the status-intervals here are not continuous, so if I group by "Status", I would always have only 2 groups for status (active and passive) and the intervals are mixed.

I'm thinking of dividing the data frame into 2 data frames: one with status "active", and one with "passive"; working separately on those two and merge together again. But this approach doesn't seem to be so efficient :( And since one customer can be active and passive many times, it's quite tricky to divide the intervals within each status-group.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Group` and by a helper Series of contiguous `Status`. With `pandas` **v 0.25.0+** you can use [named aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation), with `min`, `max` for "From" and "to" and `last` for 'Status' :

```
s = df['Status'].ne(df['Status'].shift()).cumsum()

df_new = (df.groupby(['Group', s])
          .agg(From=('Month', 'min'),
               To=('Month', 'max'),
               Status=('Status', 'last'))
           .reset_index(level=0))
```

[out]

```
         Group     From       To   Status
Status                                   
1       group1  2019-05  2019-07  Passive
2       group1  2019-08  2019-10   Active
3       group1  2019-11  2019-12  Passive
4       group2  2019-04  2019-05   Active
5       group2  2019-06  2019-08  Passive
6       group2  2019-09  2019-11   Active
6       group3  2019-12  2019-12   Active
```

---

As @nhupn points out, if using an older version of `pandas`, the aggregations can be done with:

```
df_new = (df.groupby(['Group', s])
          .agg({'Month': [('From', 'min'),
                          ('To', 'max')],
                'Status': [('Status', 'last')]})
          .reset_index(level=0))
```

Comment: Just one more thing: For pandas version <0.25, the code is like this:

`df_new = (df.groupby(['Group', s])
          .agg({'Month': [('From', 'min'), ('To', 'max')], 'Status': [('Status', 'last')]})
          .reset_index(level=0))`